# NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I have already seen that there were questions about this but no one way work for me.

I have data dt and i need to create logit model so for that numeric values are necessary.

So i tried to convert to numeric my data (dataframe).

```
  head(Perkiekmenesiumokejo)
[1] 14,00 5,00  2,00  2,00  6,00  5,00 
22 Levels: 1,00 10,00 11,00 12,00 13,00 14,00 15,00 17,00 2,00 20,00 27,00 3,00 32,00 33,00 ...
```

1)

```
> as.numeric(as.character(dt[,38]))
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [34] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [67] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

2)

```
> nr<-factor(dt[,38])
> paste( " ", nr, " ")
> as.numeric(paste( " ", nr, " "))
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [34] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

3)

```
suppressWarnings((as.numeric(as.character(dt[,38]))))
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [34] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [67] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Also several times it gave me totally different numbers then my dt[,38] are.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that R is expecting American-style numeric formatting (`,` as a thousands separator and `.` as a decimal point). A quick hack to solve this is to use the European-style CSV reader `read.csv2`:

```
Perkiekmenesiumokejo <- factor(c("14,00","5,00","2,00","2,00","6,00","5,00"))
read.csv2(text = as.character(Perkiekmenesiumokejo))[,1]
# [1] 5 2 2 6 5
```